# Тестирование базы данных MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net, сервер

Добрый день!

Есть ли какие-нибудь средства автоматизированного тестирования БД на MSSQL. Например проекты для Visual Studio (шаблоны которых я не нашел в самой студии)?

Поделитесь опытом и ссылками. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: А как Вам нужно тестировать БД? Что нет скриптовых объектов, ссылающихся на несуществующие таблицы? Это можно проверить путём их пересоздания. Для этого у нас есть внутренняя утилита.

Comment: Нужно протестировать целостность, хранимые процедуры. Нашел пример на хабре про Unit тестирование средствами .Net, что очень было бы удобно, но Database Unit Test есть только в Ultimate версии студии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал для тестирования [TSQLUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tsqlunit/) для тестиролвания SQL кода в связке со [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/) и [NUnit](http://nunit.org/).